# Access VBA: How to check if the selected file is in excel format before importing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use the below code to import csv files. I would like to modify it for excel. I changed the .csv to .xlsx but it is not working. Any help?

```
     Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
      Dim objDialog As Object
      Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With objDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .SelectedItems(1) = Trim$(.SelectedItems(1))
    .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file selected."
        Exit Sub
        ElseIf Right(.SelectedItems(1), 4) <> ".csv" Then
        MsgBox "You must select a csv (.csv) file.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is pretty simple. You're checking the last 4 characters if it's `".xlsx"`. Since `".xlsx"` is 5 characters, the last 4 characters can't be `".xlsx"`

Change the number in your `Right` to 5:

```
ElseIf Right(.SelectedItems(1), 5) <> ".xlsx" Then
```

Or do it the proper way, using filters on the filedialog, so people can only pick an xlsx:

```
With objDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx",1
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!